# Asus dsl-ac750 OpenVPN IP settings

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration, asus

I've done the VPN settings of my Asus DSL-AC750 modem. I can reach modem interface from another computer with OpenVPN. But it gives me 10.8.x.x ip block by default. My local ip starts with 192.168.1.x. So i am in the network but can not see any other device in the 192.168.1.x ip block.

Should i do anything with port routing or dmz? Not sure for this specific modem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to access the local network (other computers) on the server side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VPN Server by default is its own local network, and you can use all local resources of devices that "are also connected to the VPN server".

You can change the OpenVPN to be in bridging mode, whereby it will simply allow the remote device to get direct access to the LAN like any other device physically connected to the LAN.

On the ASUS router, you can do that by changing ***VPN Details*** to the **Advanced Settings** and change *Interface Type* from *TUN* to **TAP**:
[image]

(Another way to set that up would be to add routing rules to route from the 10.8.x.x VPN LAN to the 192.168.1.x LAN. But that's more manual work.)